# how to make width 100% on drop down ins small screen in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make notification menu like facebook, but i want to make dropdown menu 100% width when screen is small. i have found script like i want, but when i compare with my script, it same. here script that i found :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
      <title>Webslesson Tutorial | Facebook Style Header Notification using PHP Ajax Bootstrap</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
      <br /><br />
      <div class="container">
       <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Webslesson Tutorial</a>
         </div>
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<!--this part I'm focusing on-->
          <li class="dropdown">
           <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="label label-pill label-danger count" style="border-radius:10px;"></span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" style="font-size:18px;"></span></a>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li>
        <a href="#">
         <strong>ahahaha</strong><br />
         <small><em>ihihihih</em></small>
        </a>
       </li>
       <li class="divider"></li>
           </ul>
          </li>
<!----end part i'm focusing on--->
         </ul>
        </div>
       </nav>
     </body>
    </html>
```

and this is my script, focus on the notification menu. i did't see the differences. but it not 100% width when screen is small.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">  
    </head>
    <body>


        <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="container">

            <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
              <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">WEBSITE</a>
            </div>

            <div class="navbar-header pull-right">
              <ul class="nav pull-left">
<!--and this part look like same but the result is defferent--->
                <li class="dropdown pull-right">
                  <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" style="color:#777; margin-top: 5px;padding:9px 3px;background-color: transparent;" class="dropdown-toggle">@username<b class="caret"></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                      <a href="">
         <strong>ahahaha</strong><br />
         <small><em>ihihihih</em></small></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
<!--end part that i'm focused on--->            
              </ul>

              <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" class="navbar-toggle"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="visible-xs-block clearfix"></div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-left">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left">
                <li><a href="/news">Files</a></li>
                <li><a href="/news">Forums</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Shop">Project</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
              <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
               <div id="imaginary_container"> 
                    <div class="input-group stylish-input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Search" >
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <button type="submit">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                            </button>  
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>

        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Comment: you can use media media query `@media (min-width:0px) and (max-width:768px){tstyle}`

Comment: what is that? @lalitbhakuni

Comment: media query if page open in mobile change styele

Comment: read this > https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: @Mr.Pyramid it not working `@media (min-width: 768px) {
 .dropdown-menu li{
  width: 100%;
 }
}`

Comment: Share your `css/custom.css`

Comment: @Sam i don't know where i must share, than i give this link [link](https://pastebin.com/kipBQQH4)